# Glitches on iOS view transition animations

Tags: ios, animation, transition

I'm making transitions for views on my iOS app.

I'm using this way

```
   [UIView transitionWithView:self.view duration:0.5
                     options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight
                     animations:^ { [self.view addSubview:mapa.view]; }
                     completion:nil];
```

It works fine, but with certain views it cause glitches.

For example, I have a view with 2 pages at `UIScrollView`, during animation it looks like both pages has been merged and on animation finish it change to look right.

I have a lot of views with `UITableView` background color set to alpha, during animations it changes to white color without alpha.

Is there some way to fix this or its a known problem?

Maybe iOS is doing it for better GPU performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [UIViewAnimationOptionAllowAnimatedContent](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/c/econst/UIViewAnimationOptionAllowAnimatedContent), otherwise the animation is generated with a snapshot (often ignoring alphas)

> Animate the views by changing the property values dynamically and
>   redrawing 
>       the view. If this key is not present, the views are animated using a snapshot 
>       image.

Your code would look like this:

```
[UIView transitionWithView:self.view duration:0.5
                 options:(UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight|UIViewAnimationOptionAllowAnimatedContent)
                 animations:^ { [self.view addSubview:mapa.view]; }
                 completion:nil];
```